# Resharper install not detecting VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2017

I have VS 2017 Enterprise installed, previously I have the RC installed.

I had Resharper on the RC, but when I upgraded to the RTM I didn't have it any more so I uninstalled it with the plan to reinstall it.

Problem now is that the installer isn't picking up VS 2017 at all.

[image: Resharper install window]

Visual Studio details:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
Version 15.0.26228.4 D15RTWSVC
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

Installed Version: Enterprise
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repairing the Visual Studio install worked.  The Resharper installer can see Visual Studio install now.

If anyone knows *why* this was the case then I'm be interested to find out though.

Comment: Was going to try this but reinstalling ReSharper in admin mode (not sure if admin mode is necessary) worked for me.

Comment: I tried repairing the install but it still didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I "repaired" VS 2017 - not fixed.

I re-installed VS 2017 - not fixed.

I did the same with Resharper - not fixed.

I did the above in Administrator mode - not fixed.

**My Solution :** download and install the latest release of ReSharper.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered with same problem. I resolved it as explained below,

In visual studio in menu go through "tools > extension & updates". In popup select online from left side menu and search for Resharper and click install. Once installation is done close and open visual studio. Then Resharper will add automatically.

Comment: That's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok interesting !...
Faced the same issue. 
below are the steps worked for me.

1. open the command prompt.
2. copy the quoted text and pasted in your command prompt and enter "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE".
3. copy the quoted test and again pasted in command prompt and enter "devenv.exe/resetskippkgs".
4. It should open your VS 2017, wait initially it will show VS 2017 is not responding, wait for some seconds.
5. boom You can see Resharper option on the menu.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed Resharper and it is not being detected in visual studio then,
In visual studio  menu go through "tools > extension & updates". In popup select online from left side menu and search for Resharper and click enable. Then Resharper will shown automatically.